# Picture Slideshow Randomization

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently editing a website so that the slideshow on the home page appears in a different order each time that it is loaded. The code that I currently have is setup like this.

```
<div id="slideshow">

<div>

<img src="images/catpic.jpg">

</div>

<div>

<img src="images/dogpic.jpg">

</div>

.

.

</div>
```

There are 20 pictures overall and I was wondering if there was any way to do this. Also I know JavaScript and PHP in case those are needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting these images in php, you can put them into an array and use shuffle() to generate randomized array and in front-end use foreach loop to generate randomized slider.
hope this helps.